# Unwrapping Optional Int in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

The API response I am working with returns a total amount. It supports multiple different currencies, so sometimes the currency symbol will be at the front (ex. $20.00) or at the end (ex. 20.00€). I am doing a check to see if the first char of the value is an int. In this specific case, the value "20.00€" is being returned. firstChar is "2" :

DOES NOT WORK:

```
let firstNumOpt: Int? = String(firstChar).toInt()
if let num = firstNumOpt { //20.00€
   NSLog("Total: \(total)")        
}
```

WORKS:

```
if let num = String(firstChar).toInt() { //20.00€
    NSLog("Total: \(total)")        
}
```

Can someone explain why the first code block does not work? Both ways seem identical to me.
Some debug info:

> (lldb) po firstNumOpt
>       2
>        {
>         value = 2
>       }
>
> (lldb) po num
>   411432864

Comment: Working at my end. Also where and how are you initialising the total ?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you running?  Both versions work fine for me so the problem may lie outside the code you posted.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity strange. I am running Version 6.1.1. I'll try updating and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Regardless of whether it fixes the problem you should definitely upgrade, that’s pretty old and the longer you put it off the more painful it will be to upgrade your code when the time comes.  I’d also suggest reproducing the problem with a self-contained bit of code that can be pasted into a blank playground, as it doesn’t look like others can replicate the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

***Note***: This isn't really an answer, but I needed to post code to describe what was working.

I'm not sure that your error is in the code that you've posted. Here is some code that I just ran in an empty playground:

```
func test(str: String) {
  let firstNumOpt: Int? = String(str[str.startIndex]).toInt()
  if let anum = firstNumOpt {
    print("First worked on \(str)")
  }
  if let bnum = String(str[str.startIndex]).toInt() {
    print("Second worked on \(str)")
  }
}

test("20.00€") // prints "First worked on 20.00€" and "Second worked on 20.00€"
test("$20.00") // doesn't print anything
```